# Map Joda DateTime to Oracle Timestamp in Grails

Tags: oracle, grails, grails-orm, jodatime

I'm trying to map the lastUpdated, dateCreated fields in a Grails domain object to a field of type TIMESTAMP in an existing Oracle database

```
import org.grails.datastore.gorm.events.AutotimestampEventListener
import org.joda.time.*
import org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.*

class Branch {
    String idErpBranch
    String createdBy
    DateTime dateCreated
    String updatedBy
    DateTime lastUpdated

    static constraints = {

    }

    static mapping = {
        autoTimestamp true
        table 'branch'
        version false
        id column: 'id_branch'
        idErpBranch column: 'id_erp_branch'
        createdBy column: 'id_created_by'
        dateCreated column: 'ts_created'
        updatedBy column: 'id_updated_by'
        lastUpdated column: 'ts_updated'
    }
}
```

When I run grails runApp I get the following error:

```
Caused by HibernateException: Wrong column type in PRODSOA.BRANCH for column ts_created. Found: timestamp, expected: raw(255)
```

How do we map these Joda fields onto an Oracle TIMESTAMP field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the [Grails Joda plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/joda-time) you need to map the user type for each Joda type.

In [the documentation](http://gpc.github.io/grails-joda-time/guide/persistence.html) you can see that this can be done using the command `install-joda-time-gorm-mappings`:

> The Joda Time plugin can even do this for you so long as you do not
>   already have a grails.gorm.default.mapping section in your
>   Config.groovy file. Just run grails install-joda-time-gorm-mappings
>   and the plugin will add the standard mappings for all supported user
>   types to your Config.groovy file.

And if you don't need to handle the TimeZone, you can change your mapping to `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: If I run install-joda-time-gorm-mappings I get:

Error No Joda-Time Hibernate persistence API is installed

Comment: Had to add: compile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:1.9" to BuildConfig.groovy as a dependency